# How to make close button scroll down with page?

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup

So i have a popup window and on this popup i have an X button for close. The code for it is in html: `<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>`
and in js `

```
(function($) {

 /*---------------------------
Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/

  /*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes        
----------------------------*/

$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});

 /*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
 ---------------------------*/

$.fn.reveal = function(options) {


    var defaults = {  
        animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    }; 

    //Extend dem' options
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

    return this.each(function() {

   /*---------------------------
    Global Variables
    ---------------------------*/
        var modal = $(this),
            topMeasure  = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
            topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
            locked = false,
            modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

   /*---------------------------
    Create Modal BG
     ----------------------------*/
        if(modalBG.length == 0) {
            modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg"   />').insertAfter(modal);
        }           

   /*---------------------------
    Open & Close Animations
  ----------------------------*/
        //Entrance Animations
        modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
          modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
            $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
            if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modal.css({'top': $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset, 'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible'});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "top": $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                }
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modal.css({'opacity' : 0, 'visibility' : 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed/2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed/2).animate({
                        "opacity" : 1
                    }, options.animationspeed,unlockModal());                   
                } 
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'visible', 'top':$(document).scrollTop()+topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({"display":"block"});   
                    unlockModal()               
                }
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:open');
        });     

        //Closing Animation
        modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
          if(!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                        modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "fade") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "opacity" : 0
                    }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                        modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                        unlockModal();
                    });                 
                }   
                if(options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                    modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
                }       
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:close');
        });     

 /*---------------------------
   Open and add Closing Listeners
   ----------------------------*/
        //Open Modal Immediately
    modal.trigger('reveal:open')

        //Close Modal Listeners
        var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
          modal.trigger('reveal:close')
        });

        if(options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
            modalBG.css({"cursor":"pointer"})
            modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
              modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });
        }
        $('body').keyup(function(e) {
            if(e.which===27){ modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
        });


 /*---------------------------
Animations Locks
  ----------------------------*/
        function unlockModal() { 
            locked = false;
        }
        function lockModal() {
            locked = true;
        }   

    });//each call
}//orbit plugin call
  })(jQuery);
```

`

Right now X  buttom is positioned on top at all the time. How can i change the script so the  closing button will scroll down with the page? I need help because i have very little knowladge of javascript. And is there any way to change so the popup will always start from the begining after closing it and reopening and not from the content you read befour closing it?

Edit1: css:

```
/*  --------------------------------------------------
Reveal Modals
-------------------------------------------------- */

       .reveal-modal-bg { 
        position: fixed; 
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: #000;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
   z-index: 100;
   display: none;
   top: 0;
   left: 0; 
   font-family: arial;
   font-weight: bold;
     }

.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100px; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 520px;
    height: 450px;
    background: #eee url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 150%;
    }

    .reveal-modal h1{
        color: green;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: arial;
    }

    .reveal-modal strong{
        font-style: inherit;
            font-family: arial;
    }


.reveal-modal.small         { width: 200px; margin-left: -140px;}
.reveal-modal.medium        { width: 400px; margin-left: -240px;}
.reveal-modal.large         { width: 600px; margin-left: -340px;}
.reveal-modal.xlarge        { width: 800px; margin-left: -440px;}

.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: .5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rbga(0,0,0,.6);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: arial;

    }
```

Comment: u need to use CSS for that. post your css.

Comment: i editet my post with css

Comment: is this reveal modal from ZURB? you want whole modal to scroll through the page?

Comment: yes that is the one. I want the closing button (x) to scroll down with the page insted of staying at the top as it is now.

Comment: Can you provide working example of that popup? Some how I can't figure out, what you are trying to do. As was suggested below, the `position:fixed` will make your button stay at the same place even if you scroll. Try adding `z-index` with some high value. The button may be hidden below something else. And how do you want to reset the state of the popup? To delete text from some div or what? You can place your reset code to this block of code `modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {...`

Answer (score 1):

This would do the work.

```
.close-reveal-modal {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: If i do that it dissapears